# Credentials do not exist in Curve 8520 while using wi-fi

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-storm, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

I have the following exception while I try to login in my application in curve 8520 using wi-fi

> "Credentials do not exist"

same application works before. but suddenly this exception comes.

I can access the internet services as well as open webpages using wi-fi.

but at the time of login my application "Credentials do not exist" exception comes.

I also cheched that at the time of clicked the application icon,device registration works. .

application works fine with using http connection without using wi-fi.

problem comes only when I try to login via wi-fi

Answer (score 0):

Maybe post your connect URL? It sounds like you're mixing up the appenders for APN and wifi. "Credentials do not exist" sounds like APN fail.

Wifi should be:

deviceside=true;interface=wifi

APN is just deviceside=true, if you have default APN configured. If not, you get a credentials fail. So maybe you're just missing that wifi signifier?